# get args from message content

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
var number = args.slice(1).join(' ');
var amount = args.slice(2).join(' ');

const PaymentEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Payment`)
  .setColor('#ccccff')
  .addField(`For ${number}, csgo commends\n
    Please send **${amount}€** through paypal\n`);

message.channel.send(PaymentEmbed);
```

By using `!command n 100 1` I get up with this message:

> For 100 1, csgo commends
> Please send 1€ through paypal
> :warning: LEAVE THE PAYMENT DESCRIPTION / MESSAGE EMPTY :warning: undefined

I shouldn't get `undefined` and at the first array I get "100 1" and I should only see "100".

Comment: Could we see more of your command, please? It is hard to start helping you without seeing the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the standard way to collect the arguments from a message. In this case "args" is an array and you can access its values by index.

```js
const number = args[1];
const amount = args[2];
```

These are example indexes and you might need to change them to get the correct input values.